# Getting BandAccessDeniedException from BackgroundTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, microsoft-band

Windows Phone 8.1 (Store) app, MS Band SDK v1.3.20217

Foreground app works great, as a user I've granted access to talk to the Band in question. I get to the point where I'm

```
client = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(band);
```

and I'm met with

```
Microsoft.Band.BandAccessDeniedException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Band.BandAccessDeniedException' in Microsoft.Band.Store.DLL
Additional information: A non-specific error occurred while attempting to acquire the Bluetooth device service. This error can occur if the application manifest does not have the required permissions for opening the Bluetooth connection to the Microsoft Band, or if the user denies access.
```

though my app manifest has:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest">
      <Device Id="any">
        <!-- Used by the Microsoft Band SDK -->
        <Function Type="serviceId:A502CA9A-2BA5-413C-A4E0-13804E47B38F" />
        <!-- Used by the Microsoft Band SDK -->
        <Function Type="serviceId:C742E1A2-6320-5ABC-9643-D206C677E580" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

When I get the target band from the Client Manager, I'm doing:

```
var bands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync(true);
band = bands.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == targetBandName);
```

so I'm denoting this is being initiated from the background and it successfully gives me back a `Microsoft.Band.Store.BluetoothDeviceInfo` instance to throw in to `ConnectAsync`

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

if I change `GetBandsAsync(true)` to just `GetBandsAsync()` this problem goes away. It appears there's a bug in `ConnectAsync` when the `BluetoothDeviceInfo` instance came from `GetBandsAsync(true)`

Answer (score 1):

Stupid answer, but in case anyone finds this as I did through Bing:

2.3.1 from the SDK docs: "the application will need to declare the appropriate privileges that are needed to access Bluetooth hardware resources. To do this, manually update the Capabilities section of the application’s Package.appxmanifest file to include the following"

...and basically, it's a checkbox in the Package.appxmanifest Capabilities tab. Yes, this is obvious but I wasn't aware of it. HTH someone.

NB: This is orthogonal to the issue b3tech was seeing but manifested the same.